# Logic of string termination literal in python (namely the single and double quotes)

Tags: python, string, quotes, double-quotes

In a python script or IDLE shell, we can print texts using double quotes `"` or single quote `'` or a combination of three single or double quotes (mostly used in docstrings) `'''`.

I was working with some text and tried out the following:
`''''4''''` there was an EOL while scanning text.
Then I tried it this time using 5 quotes, i.e. `'''''4'''''` and the output was `"''4"`.

Finally, I tried the same with a large number of quotes:

**INPUT**

`>>> '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''ff'''''''''''''''''''''''''''`

**OUTPUT**

`"''ff"`

---

I cannot understand why python returns such an output given such a large number of `'`.

**Question:** How does it show such an anomalous output, what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple FSM (three primary states: in code, in string, in docstring) consuming the input to handle single quotes. When it is in code and it encounters three quotes in a row, it enters the docstring state. It stays in the docstring state until it encounters three quotes of the same type. When it is in code and encounters fewer than three quotes in a row, it enters a string state, and stays in that state until it encounters an (unescaped) quote (which may be immediately).

When this FSM is in the code state and encounters a long sequence of quotes (matching the RE `/'{3,}/`), it enters and exits the docstring state (no non-delimiters are encountered, so the strings are all empty) until the last few quote characters, at which point it's either still in the docstring state (and any remaining quotes are in the string) or it's in the code state, and any remaining quotes are interpreted as string delimiters. If it's in the string or docstring state went it encounters a long sequence of quotes, it will first transition to the code state, then every three quotes will transition between code and docstring states. Any remaining quotes at the end are interpreted as previously mentioned.

An actual FSM will require additional states beyond the 3 primary, but they're an implementation detail and not conceptually significant. The FSM can be easily extended to handle double-quotes as well by duplicating the single-quote states & transitions and modifying as appropriate for double-quotes.

Writing a formal description of the FSM and calculating final states from initial states based on the count of consecutive quotes (i.e. write a function `end_state(initial_state, consecutive_quote_count)`) left as exercises.

Answer (score 2):

`'''''4'''''` is parsed as

- `'''` (open string literal)
- `''4` (content of the string)
- `'''` (close string literal)
- `''` (an empty string literal)

I'm not doing the whole long one. But each `''''''` is an empty triple-quoted string literal, so it's along the same lines.